# Como lidar com requisitos que "misturam" domínio e interface?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, ddd

Sempre que eu desenvolvo algum software eu tento deixar o modelo de domínio sem ser influenciado por questões relativas as outras camadas da aplicação como tecnologias em geral e questões de interface.

Na verdade, o modelo de domínio contém um modelo em código do problema sendo resolvido, e o objetivo é encapsular as regras e lógicas de negócio. Toda a funcionalidade em si deve estar dentro dele.

Acontece que recentemente em um projeto recebi um requerimento do seguinte tipo:

> No cadastro de status de contato deve ser possível escolher uma cor para aquele status. A partir daí, ao listar os contatos em uma tabela, a linha de um contato deve ser pintada com a cor correspondente do seu status.

O requerimento é bem simples e a implementação também. Acontece só que eu fiquei um pouco preocupado porque me parece que para implementar isso acabamos misturando o domínio com questões de interface.

Na realidade, o jeito mais prático que eu imagino de fazer isso seria: dada a classe `StatusContato` adiciona-se uma propriedade `Cor` do tipo string que guarda um código hexadecimal da cor. A partir daí a interface gerencia como essa cor é salva e usada.

Apesar de funcionar, isso é preocupante. Se pensarmos só no domínio, só no negócio, `Cor` não é uma característica e nem algo associado a `StatusContato`. É meramente algo da interface de usuário.

Eu consigo imaginar vários outros requisitos desse tipo, onde o usuário ao apresentar o requisito mistura questões de domínio com questões de interface.

Nesse sentido, como esse impasse pode ser resolvido? Como esse tipo de requisito pode ser tratado sem acabar poluindo o modelo de domínio com questões de interface?

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que não é exatamente um problema de ultrapassar camadas. Você está muito focado no domínio como uma coisa abstrata e esquecendo que a camada de negócio tem que modelar o problema do cliente, e não um problema genérico.

**Para o seu cliente, `StatusDoContato` tem uma cor**. Pode ser que o `StatusDoContato` de uma empresa concorrente não tenha, mas o do seu cliente tem.

Isso não quer dizer, é claro, que não há espaço para a separação de responsabilidades. É papel da camada de Apresentação decidir onde ela vai mostrar essa cor (e **como** vai e até **se** vai), mas é papel das outras camadas armazenarem e gerenciarem a cor salva. Se vier um requisito no futuro que diz, por exemplo, que o usuário pode selecionar uma cor dentre várias pré-definidas e rotuladas (vermelho, azul, roxo), vai ter uma parte disso na Apresentação (uma lista de seleção) e uma parte na camada de negócio (converter esse valor selecionado em um hexadecimal e mandar salvar).

Moral da história: se você pensar do jeito que estar pensando, até mesmo o nome do status vai poder ser visto como uma parte da camada de Apresentação, já que ele tem uma representação visual (caracteres na tela) e pode estar sendo exibido. Seu Modelo e sua camada de negócio têm que modelar os dados e o domínio do seu cliente e seu cliente quer um software, no fim das contas.